# View() keyboard shortcut

Tags: r, rstudio

I just got done browsing the keyboard shortcuts for RStudio and I can't find one for `View()`. Does this exist in any form?

I'd like to highlight any data frame in my source pane and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> or whatever to see the spreadsheet view of my data frame in RStudio. I often create data frames and I have to jump to the console and type `View(data_frame)` to make sense of the data frame. Because the tibble view is too condensed. I know I can highlight the data frame in source and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> but that just yields the condensed tibble view.

Comment: I don't think there's a default shortcut for it. Try creating an [addin](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/)

Comment: You might also consider a [snippet](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although not documented, <kbd>F2</kbd> should work in recent RStudio versions.

(It does work for me for version 1.1.423 on Linux and Windows, but [this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/1861) is still open on their GitHub.)

Comment: This works when you select a single variable, but how to do that for an entire pipeline?

Answer (score 8):

You just hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and click (with left mouse button) on the name of the data frame in your script (in RStudio).

Comment: This was edited to "double click", but for me it definitely works with single click. If it's different for you, please clarify in a comment.

Comment: How to do that for an entire pipeline?

Answer (score 5):

I did not know about the <kbd>F2</kbd> shortcut, so I put together my own shortcut using the `rstudioapi` package, which I find now having upgraded Rstudio to be superior.

You'll find the details [here](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/rstudio_addins.html#keyboard-shorcuts) on how to bind a function to the Rstudio shortcut list. To create and persist a shortcut using this package, I understand that it needs to be a part of a package you have installed (instructions in the link), so you will need to set that up. I have done this, but the package is not published so you would need to create your own package or add it to an existing one. Once it is set up, the package does not need to be loaded to use the function shortcut.

My `view` shortcut does the following: grabs the text from the entire line which the cursor is on and calls `view` with it as the argument.

This works then when you have performed some filtering or subsetting on the data. I use `data.table`, so often I will have something like `iris[, sum(Sepal.Width), by=.(Species)]`. With my shortcut, I can have the cursor anywhere on that line, hit the shortcut and view the resulting `data.table`. It wouldn't work on a multi-line `dplyr` query, but perhaps could be expanded in a way.

Edit: it is superior because the <kbd>F2</kbd> shortcut only seems to work on an un-modified `data.frame` (`data.table` etc.) when the cursor is immediately before, after or inside the text.

Here is the function:

```
viewshortcut <- function(){

  dr123 <- rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()

  row786 <- dr123$selection[[1]]$range$end[1]
  end786 <- dr123$selection[[1]]$range$end

  dr123 <- rstudioapi::document_range(
    start = rstudioapi::document_position(row = row786, column = 1),
    end = rstudioapi::document_position(row = row786, column = 1000)
  )

  dr123 <- rstudioapi::setSelectionRanges(dr123)

  dr123 <- rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()

  dr123 <- dr123$selection[[1]]$text
  dr123 <- paste0("View(", dr123, ")")
  print(dr123)
  eval(parse(text=dr123))


}
```

Answer (score 1):

To modify current keyboard short-cuts you can go to `Tools -> Modify Keyboard Shortcuts` but there's none for View() function

R [documentation](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206382178?version=1.1.383&mode=desktop) says you can add user-defined functions and key shortcuts but there's not explanation. turns out it's out of date and you should try an [addin](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/) now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rstudio, you could click the dataframe on your environment. It will open the dataframe as a tab for a spreadsheet view.